unable to access vaex dataframe
I am using Vaex for the first time. With vaex.example(), I can save the dataframelocal as df. However, with real world data, this doesn't seem possible. See screenshot below.

I'm unable to do an MRE as it's dependent on a large-scale dataframe, but has anyone seen this before? Am I misunderstanding how vaex is meant to be used?
